# How to get first item from XmlSchema.Elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, .net-4.5

I have XmlSchema object. Which has Elements property. **I need a first element** from it. I cant figure how to get it not writing foreach/break (which would look stupid). Is there a nice way?

**EDIT:** the only way I found is : getenumerator/movenext/value;

**EDIT2:** one of the ways is to cast XmlSchema.Elements.Values (ICollection) to a meaningful type to use with Linq. The problem is that I cant find that type. The GetType gives me name: "System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaObjectTable+ValuesCollection"

I dont see this type in the ObjectExplorer and I cant cast to it..

**Please answer if you have working solution** rather than just throwing in whatever comes to your head. Thanks.

Comment: look into using linq.

Comment: Can't you take the first item by taking Items.First() property of your element ?

Comment: linq works with ienumerable. this is not it.

Comment: Maybe check the `System.XML.Extensions` namespace? It looks like it defines its own LINQ extensions, one of which is XElements() which does expose IEnumerable<Element>.

Comment: @KyleBaran I cant find it. The closest I see is : System.Xml.Linq namespace which has Extensions class in it. Which has Elements method. But not XElements. I use .NET 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use linq on the Names or Values of the elements, depending on what you need

E.g.,

```
var v = yourObject.Elements.Names.OfType<XmlQualifiedName>().FirstOrDefault();
var w = yourObject.Elements.Values.OfType<XmlSchemaElement>().FirstOrDefault();
```

===

Edited: Added OfType<> to get an ICollection<> instead of an ICollection so that it is possible to use FirstOrDefault

Note: I verified this solution on the example XmlSchema from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, if your element names or values have a different type you'll need to change that in the OfType<>

Comment: Are you sure such properties and methods exist?

Comment: Please give a working solution as an answer and not a dart in the dark... There are Names and Values but (see my EDIT2) - **I dont know how to cast them correctly** to apply LINQ. If you tell me I will mark you answer!